# How to fix max_length and max_features?

Tags: text-classification, bert-language-model

I am working on text classification using the pre-trained language model BERT. I don't understand how to fix some parameters like max_features and max_length. In other words, how can I choose the efficient value of max_features and max_length for good model performance (good accuracy).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: This kind of non-programming question is better asked on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. This is a case of (hyper)parameter tuning: basically the idea is to try many different values and select the one which gives the best performance. This step should be done on a validation set, not the final test set.